# syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: bash, shell-script, process-substitution

I am writing a script to read the output of a command to variable a and b. This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)

echo "The value of a is $a"
echo "The value of b is $b"
```

and getting the syntax error as :

```
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
line 3: `read a b < <(awk /Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{echo "%s ", $7} /tmp/ServerState)'
```

But when I am typing the same command in the console it is working for me without any issue.

```
app@user:/tmp> read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)
app@user:/tmp> echo $a
FAILED
app@user:/tmp> echo $b
STARTED
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this behavior from script. How are you invoking the script? I am invoking as: `$ ./script.sh`

Comment: @Ketan I am invoking it as sh script.sh. Just now I tried using ./script.sh and it is giving the desire result. The value of a is FAILED
The value of b is STARTED. Thank You so much for the response...Just want to know why it is different while executing the same script using sh file.sh and ./file.sh ??

Comment: Suppose `sh` don't allow command substitution. Try invoke by `bash script.sh`. Same calling by `./script.sh` executes with `sha-bang` which is /bin/**bash** in your script.

Comment: @SudevJash see: [What is the difference between ./ and sh to run a script?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script)

Comment: @Costas Yes it is working fine even with bash script.sh and I am getting the desired output... Thank You so much...

Comment: @SudevJash May be you can answer your question and select it as the right answer for the record.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sh` (which in most (Debian-derived) systems is linked to `dash`) doesn't allow *process substitution*. Try invoke by `bash script.sh`. Same calling by ./script.sh executes with `sha-bang` which is **`/bin/bash`** in your script.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Ah, your modification now means the opposite of what I meant to say.

Comment: @muru I can't accept modification to `bash`. I mean `dash` exactly. `file $(which sh)` output `/bin/sh: symbolic link to 'dash'`

Comment: Costas, that's what I meant. Michael Durrant changed my edit to replace `dash` with `bash`. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: You mean process substitution (`<( echo foo )`), not command substitution (`$(echo foo)`) (which is part of the POSIX specification).

Comment: @chepner You are right. Thank you for comment. Repaired.

Comment: thanks a lot! I always use sh xxx.sh to run my script until one day I include the process substitution: "<()" in it. I got problem! even though I add #!/bin/bash in the beginning, it still not working! Then I use bash xxx.sh to run, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to invoke the script as sh file.sh and was getting the error. But when i invoked the same script as ./file.sh and bash file.sh it is working and giving the desired result.